# iPhone iOS how to create tints and shades programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uicolor

I'm doing a lot of programmatic interface customization, such as gradients and borders, and am interested in how I can modify a color (given it's HSV or RGB value) to produce tints and shades (see example). I know that tint is a color + white, while shade is a color + black.

**Is there some algorithm I can use to take a default iOS color, like Blue, and create several tints and shades of that color programmatically?**

Thank you!

[image: Tints and shades]

[Creating tints and shades](http://www.sccc.premiumdw.com/web200/creating-tints-shades-in-illustrator/)

Comment: dont think there's anything "built in"... you'll have to try to find some HSV algorithms for C and use those.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I am not at my computer so I cannot write the algorithm out, but this is the method you need:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHue:(CGFloat)hue saturation:(CGFloat)saturation brightness:(CGFloat)brightness alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

You choose your starting Hue and Saturation (saturation should probably be at 1.0, but do whatever is right for your situation) and then you increment the bright value in a loop to get the new shade. Probably best to have an array that you can put the colors in then you can return that array and use it as needed.

Comment: It is possible to get a shade by decrementing brightness. Built-in colors start with brightness of 1.0 (max). Adding white to create tints appears to be more complex

Answer (score 0):

This is the tool I use for getting hex values for tints and shades: http://slayeroffice.com/tools/color_palette/

It's basically the HTML equivalent of my tutorial you are pointing to.

Answer (score -2):

You can use.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:29.0/255.0 green:42.0/255.0 blue:74.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

for example if you have to give tint color of navigation bar than

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:29.0/255.0 green:42.0/255.0 blue:74.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He is looking for an algorithm to create different shades from a single color.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to avoid hard-coding anything,  and instead would like to use colors like "20% shade of blue" or "10% tint of red" in my interfaces.